# Use a switch case for a verification function (LWJGL keyboard input)?

Tags: java, switch-statement, lwjgl

**What the title says. Is it possible?**
As far as I know, there is no `getKeyPressed` or anything of the sort. I want to use a switch case for organization (and practice) as well as speed (or so I was informed).

Basically, the switch case clause(?) is just a boolean return. But how can I check if a key is pressed based on a value passed into it without a pasta bowl of if / else statements?

Obviously this code doesn't work, but I'm looking for something like it.

```
public void moveCamera() {
    switch (Keyboard.isKeyDown(!!!CASE CHECKING HERE!!!)) {
        case Keyboard.KEY_W:
            position.z -= MOVE_SPEED;
            break;

        case Keyboard.KEY_A:
            position.x += MOVE_SPEED;
            break;

        case Keyboard.KEY_S:
            position.z -= MOVE_SPEED;
            break;

        case Keyboard.KEY_D:
            position.x += MOVE_SPEED;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would typically need an event listener for this.  Note that this isn't possible from a console program.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's LWJGL so obviously not a console application. But how heavy would an event listener be?

Comment: Just Google for it, or check Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Oracle documentation on Key Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: You can switch on getEventKey(). This will hit your current cases and then you can wrap the whole switch statement with if (getEventKeyState()) {switch/case}. There is no need to use an event listener.

Comment: @KylonTyner I did indeed figure that out. But I now made a new algorithm for key input when I rewrote the class entirely. It started to get messy so I just rewrote it. I might post an answer myself and include your idea.

Comment: Good! Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a solution that I liked (but did not try) from *@KysonTyner*.**

> You can switch on `getEventKey()`. This will hit your current cases and then you can wrap the whole switch statement with if `(getEventKeyState()) {switch/case}`. There is no need to use an event listener. – Kylon Tyner

As for what I used, I abandoned the idea of a switch entirely, as I realized that the movement speed would multiply if there were more than one direction of input.

I wanted to support multiple directions of motion for diagonal movement, so it wouldn't be "ghosting" as keys were pressed.

What I did is separate the functions, one to test keyboard input, and one to move the camera. There doesn't have to be any special logic for the key input, as it simply passes an LWJGL `Vector3f` to the camera move function.

Then, in camera move, I normalized that vector and altered the positions accordingly.

This is a simplified version of my Camera class for demonstration. I removed everything except translation.

```
package spikespaz.engine.main;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

// Created by spike on 7/3/2017.
public final class Camera {
    private Camera() {}

    private float moveSpeed = 0.2f;
    private Vector3f position = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);

    public Camera(Vector3f position, Vector3f rotation) {
        this.position = position;
    }

            public void updateKeyInput() {
        Vector3f direction = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
            direction.x = 1;
        } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
            direction.x = -1;
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
            direction.y = -1;
        } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LSHIFT)) {
            direction.y = 1;
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
            direction.z = 1;
        } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
            direction.z = -1;
        }

        translate(direction);
    }

    private void translate(Vector3f direction) {
        Vector3f normalized = direction.normalise(null);
        Vector3f.add(position, (Vector3f) normalized.scale(moveSpeed), position);
    }

    public float getMoveSpeed() {
        return moveSpeed;
    }

    public void setMoveSpeed(float moveSpeed) {
        this.moveSpeed = moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

Translate is relative. In the full class I have another function to set absolute position, without the move speed.

In the above example, the input vector for translate is simply a direction. The function should coordinate that based on the movement speed for each frame.

Comment: Glad to see that you found a solution that works! If you're interested...creating relative movement in this way will allow the moving entity to move much faster when holding A/W, W/D, D/S, S/A as it is applying roughly 1.414 units of translation. Whereas when you are only holding one of the directional keys (W, A, S, D) it is applying exactly 1 unit of translation. To fix this, you can use sin/cos functions relative to the angle of the entity. (for some games, this makes a huge difference)

Comment: @KylonTyner I see your point, it would also move faster than 1.414 units if they were in motion in all three axis, as an example for admins on servers. But I thought the normalization of the input vector would fix this issue by reducing the sum to one unit. Is this not the case?